# PHP Code ('exec("echo $HOME")') cannot get HOME environment variable

Tags: php

Some PHP Code cannot get HOME environment variable.

```
getenv('HOME'); // OK

exec("env",$out);
print_r($out,1); // OK

exec("echo $HOME", $out);
print_r($out,1); // NG
```

Comment: Exec probably doesn't set any environment variables. You could try `exec("export", $out); print_r($out,1);` to see which env vars are set. Note however, that using exec like you are doing won't work on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your string is in double quotes and PHP is substituting the value of the variable `$HOME`. Try changing the string to use single quotes.  I.e.

```
exec('echo $HOME', $out);
```